# Select dropdown inputting more than one select. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I am trying to get my select to only print one address instead of two. When I select TMobile, it will do the print to the input just fine. However, if I also select Verizon, it will also add the Verizon address next to it.

```
 <select class='cellBox' id='cellSelection'>
  <option value='@tmomail.next'>TMobile</option>
  <option value='@vzwireless.com'>Verizon</option>
 </select>
 <input type='text' class='histBox' id='resultCell'>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
 var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('cellSelection2');
 var textbook2 = document.getElementById('resultCell2');
 dropdown2.onchange = function(){
                        textbook2.value += this.value;
                      }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Share the html too.

Comment: So what should happen if you select both carriers?

Comment: well, you are concatenating strings that is why it is adding up, try `textbook2.value = this.value;` without `+`

Comment: @BakhtiiarMuzakparov Dang.. Should have noticed that... Thanks!

Comment: @I'mjustacoderforfun check the answer I modified the code it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('cellSelection');
 var textbook2 = document.getElementById('resultCell');
 dropdown2.addEventListener("change",function(){
   textbook2.value = dropdown2.value;
 });
```

```html
<select class='cellBox' id='cellSelection'>
  <option value='@tmomail.next'>TMobile</option>
  <option value='@vzwireless.com'>Verizon</option>
 </select>
 <input type='text' class='histBox' id='resultCell'>
```

Comment: Nice! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are concatenating the dropdown value in the `onchange` event.

Change from `textbook2.value += this.value;` to `textbook2.value = this.value;`

Comment: Duh... Rookie mistake. *facepalm* Thanks!